Tauri Linux [Platform does not support navigator.requestMediaKeySystemAccess]?
I would like to turn my Sveltekit Spotify Player into a Linux app using Tauri.
Everything works fine on Windows, but on Linux:

Unhandled Promise Rejection: EMEError: Platform does not support navigator.requestMediaKeySystemAccess.

Full code on GitHub
if ($isSpotifySdkReady) {
                const authCode = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get(
                    'code'
                );
                if (authCode) {
                    await newAccessToken(clientID, authCode);
                    window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, window.location.origin + window.location.pathname);
                }

                // noinspection JSUnresolvedReference
                player = new Spotify.Player({
                    name: 'SoundSphere',
                    getOAuthToken: cb => {
                        cb(getAccessToken(clientID));
                    },
                    volume: 1
                });

                if (localStorage.getItem('spotifyAccessToken') !== null) loggedIn = true;
                else loading = false;
                player.connect();


webkitgtk used by Tauri doesnt support DRM APIs in general and unfortunately there is no fix at the moment

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
